# How to solve the error: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method

Tags: php

This project worked for sometime and i haven't done any changes to it. One day, i was just curious and decided to check on it but now it doesn't work anymore.

> Notice: Undefined index: type in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icilending/web/actions.php on
>   line 5
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   second array member is not a valid method in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/icilending/web/actions.php on
>   line 5

Code:

```
require_once("../src/inc/init.php");

call_user_func([new Controller, $_POST['type']]);
```

Comment: _“second array member is not a valid method”_ - so what _is_ the actual value of that second array item …?

Comment: You might also want to validate to make sure `$_POST['type']` contains a valid method name before you try and use it as one.